# ember-simple-auth: Error: Assertion Failed: The route index was not found

Tags: ember-cli, ember-simple-auth

I am building an app with the use of ember-simple-auth.

So it looks very much like the library its doing is thing.

Here is what happens:

1. user tries to access /dashboard but is redirected to /
2. the route / contains the login form
3. the user logs in with valid credentials
4. Server responds: /token 200 0.252 ms - 52
5. But an error message is shown: Error: Assertion Failed: The route index was not found
6. user navigates to /dashboard and can now see the content, navigate around protected areas, and successfully log out.

**My question is**, how do I define /dashboard as the route instead of index? So that after successful login you are redirected to /dashboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure Ember Simple Auth's [`routeAfterAuthentication`](http://ember-simple-auth.com/api/classes/Configuration.html#property_routeAfterAuthentication) in the config, e.g.

```
ENV['ember-simple-auth'] = {
  routeAfterAuthentication: 'dashboard'
}
```

Comment: Hi marcoow,

I just found that out as well. After changing the routeAfterAuthentication I stumbled upon some really weird bahaviour. I am making a new question and accepting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

4 years later...

On Ember Simple Auth Part, you can add `routeAfterAuthentication` and call it a day, because of ESA default to `index`.

If we dig deeper, as far as why ESA was and still defaults to the `Index` route, is that Ember always generates 2 routes for you:

- one `""` for ApplicationRoute
- and `"/"` for IndexRoute,

You get these 2 routes for free.

[image]
*I found [3.20](https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.20.0/routing/defining-your-routes/) version doc's wording is verbose, so I'm pasting from [1.10](https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/routing/defining-your-routes/) doc, but the idea remains the same*

On that perspective, ESA uses `IndexRoute` as default is a safe bet.